# Create a line connecting circles upon mouse hover

Tags: d3.js

I have a scatter plot made in D3 with circles denoting each data point. Here's my code:

```
viz.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.x)})
  .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.y)})
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {return d.color})
  .on('mouseover', function(d){
      console.log(d.color)
  })
```

What I would like to do is, when a given circle is hovered on, connect all circles through a line that have the same color. How can I do this? I can get the color logged into the console, but I don't understand how I can connect all points with the same color through a line upon mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a class with color code to your circles. Use d3.selectAll to retrieve all of them on mouseover. Then retrieve their coordinates and pass the coordinates to draw d3.svg.line.

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
        return 'dot color-' + color(d.species).replace('#','');
      })
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.sepalWidth); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sepalLength); })
    .attr("dot-color", function(d) { return color(d.species).replace('#',''); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); })
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.selectAll(".color-" + $(this).attr("dot-color"))
          .attr("r", 5.5);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.selectAll(".color-" + $(this).attr("dot-color"))
          .attr("r", 3.5);
    });
```

Here's an example with color hover:

http://vida.io/documents/KinEKRkSPSfStA4Eu

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without relying on a common class attribute. In the mouseover handler:

```
d3.selectAll('.dot')
  .filter(function (dOther) { return d.color == dOther.color })
  .attr('r', 3.5)
```