# How to draw vertical and horzontial line for bubble in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have generated a graph like this

http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/what-makes-us-happy/

I want to make an x-line and y-line for indiduval bubbles when hover.is that possible??. Any suggestions are welcomed.

main.js

```
// HELPERS
function parseData(d) {
  var keys = _.keys(d[0]);
  return _.map(d, function(d) {
    var o = {};
    _.each(keys, function(k) {
      if( k == 'Country' )
        o[k] = d[k];
      else
        o[k] = parseFloat(d[k]);
    });
    return o;
  });
}

function getBounds(d, paddingFactor) {
  // Find min and maxes (for the scales)
  paddingFactor = typeof paddingFactor !== 'undefined' ? paddingFactor : 1;

  var keys = _.keys(d[0]), b = {};
  _.each(keys, function(k) {
    b[k] = {};
    _.each(d, function(d) {
      if(isNaN(d[k]))
        return;
      if(b[k].min === undefined || d[k] < b[k].min)
        b[k].min = d[k];
      if(b[k].max === undefined || d[k] > b[k].max)
        b[k].max = d[k];
    });
    b[k].max > 0 ? b[k].max *= paddingFactor : b[k].max /= paddingFactor;
    b[k].min > 0 ? b[k].min /= paddingFactor : b[k].min *= paddingFactor;
  });
  return b;
}

function getCorrelation(xArray, yArray) {
  function sum(m, v) {return m + v;}
  function sumSquares(m, v) {return m + v * v;}
  function filterNaN(m, v, i) {isNaN(v) ? null : m.push(i); return m;}

  // clean the data (because we know that some values are missing)
  var xNaN = _.reduce(xArray, filterNaN , []);
  var yNaN = _.reduce(yArray, filterNaN , []);
  var include = _.intersection(xNaN, yNaN);
  var fX = _.map(include, function(d) {return xArray[d];});
  var fY = _.map(include, function(d) {return yArray[d];});

  var sumX = _.reduce(fX, sum, 0);
  var sumY = _.reduce(fY, sum, 0);
  var sumX2 = _.reduce(fX, sumSquares, 0);
  var sumY2 = _.reduce(fY, sumSquares, 0);
  var sumXY = _.reduce(fX, function(m, v, i) {return m + v * fY[i];}, 0);

  var n = fX.length;
  var ntor = ( ( sumXY ) - ( sumX * sumY / n) );
  var dtorX = sumX2 - ( sumX * sumX / n);
  var dtorY = sumY2 - ( sumY * sumY / n);

  var r = ntor / (Math.sqrt( dtorX * dtorY )); // Pearson ( http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node122.html )
  var m = ntor / dtorX; // y = mx + b
  var b = ( sumY - m * sumX ) / n;

  // console.log(r, m, b);
  return {r: r, m: m, b: b};
}


d3.json('ceral.json', function(data) {

    var xAxis = 'Weight', yAxis = 'Height';
  var xAxisOptions = ["Bp_Systolic", "Bp_Diastolic","Height", "Weight", "Bmi","A1C","Cholestrol"]
   var yAxisOptions = ["Bp_Systolic", "Bp_Diastolic","Height","Weight", "Bmi","A1C","Cholestrol"];
  var descriptions = {
    "Bp_Systolic" : "Bp_Systolic (mm Hg)",
    "Bp_Diastolic" : "Bp_Diastolic (mm Hg)",
    "Weight" : "Weight (lbs)",
    "Height" : "Height (inches)",
    "Bmi"    : "Bmi (kg/m2)",
    "A1C"    :  "A1C (%)",
    "Cholestrol":"Cholestrol (mg/dl)"
    };
     var description = {
    "Bp_Systolic" : "Bp_Systolic (mm Hg)",
    "Bp_Diastolic" : "Bp_Diastolic (mm Hg)",
    "Weight" : "Weight (lbs)",
    "Height" : "Height (inches)",
    "Bmi"    : "Bmi (kg/m2)",
    "A1C"    :  "A1C (%)",
    "Cholestrol":"Cholestrol (mg/dl)"
    };


   var line;
  var keys = _.keys(data[0]);
 // alert(keys);
  var data = parseData(data);
 // alert(data.toSource());
  var bounds = getBounds(data, 1);
 // alert(bounds.toSource());

  // SVG AND D3 STUFF
  var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 640);
  var xScale, yScale;

  svg.append('g')
    .classed('chart', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(80, -60)');



  // Build menus
  d3.select('#x-axis-menu')
    .selectAll('li')
    .data(xAxisOptions)
    .enter()
    .append('li')
    .text(function(d) {return d;})
    .classed('selected', function(d) {
      return d === xAxis;
    })
    .on('click', function(d) {
      xAxis = d;
     // alert(xAxis);
      updateChart();
      updateMenus();
    });



     d3.select('#y-axis-menu')
    .selectAll('li')
    .data(yAxisOptions)
    .enter()
    .append('li')
    .text(function(d) {return d;})
    .classed('selected', function(d) {
      return d === yAxis;
    })
    .on('click', function(d) {
      yAxis = d;
     // alert(xAxis);
      updateChart();
      updateMenus();
    });


  // Country name
  d3.select('svg g.chart')
    .append('text')
    .attr({'id': 'countryLabel', 'x': 0, 'y': 130})
      .style({'font-size': '40px', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'fill': '#ddd'});

  // Best fit line (to appear behind points)
  d3.select('svg g.chart')
    .append('line')
    .attr('id', 'bestfit');


  // Axis labels
  d3.select('svg g.chart')
    .append('text')
    .attr({'id': 'xLabel', 'x': 400, 'y': 670, 'text-anchor': 'middle'})
    .text(descriptions[xAxis]);

  d3.select('svg g.chart')
    .append('text')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-60, 330)rotate(-90)')
    .attr({'id': 'yLabel', 'text-anchor': 'middle'})
    .text(descriptions[yAxis]);

  // Render points
  updateScales();
  var pointColour = d3.scale.category20b();




  d3.select('svg g.chart')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      // alert(d.toSource());
      // alert(d[xAxis]);
     // alert(xScale(d[xAxis]).toSource());
      return isNaN(d[xAxis]) ? d3.select(this).attr('cx') : xScale(d[xAxis]);
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return isNaN(d[yAxis]) ? d3.select(this).attr('cy') : yScale(d[yAxis]);
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {return pointColour(i);})
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')

     .on('mouseover', function(d) {
         d3.select('svg g.chart #countryLabel')
        .html("ID:"+d.Patient_id+" ["+d[xAxis]+","+d[yAxis]+"] ")
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', 1)






        })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                d3.select('svg g.chart #countryLabel')
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .style('opacity', 0);
    })




  updateChart(true);
  updateMenus();

  // Render axes
  d3.select('svg g.chart')
    .append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 630)')
    .attr('id', 'xAxis')
    .call(makeXAxis);

  d3.select('svg g.chart')
    .append("g")
    .attr('id', 'yAxis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-10, 0)')
    .call(makeYAxis);


  //// RENDERING FUNCTIONS
  function updateChart(init) {
    updateScales();

    d3.select('svg g.chart')
      .selectAll('circle')
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease('quad-out')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return isNaN(d[xAxis]) ? d3.select(this).attr('cx') : xScale(d[xAxis]);
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return isNaN(d[yAxis]) ? d3.select(this).attr('cy') : yScale(d[yAxis]);
      })
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return isNaN(d[xAxis]) || isNaN(d[yAxis]) ? 0 : 5;
      });

    // Also update the axes
    d3.select('#xAxis')
      .transition()
      .call(makeXAxis);

    d3.select('#yAxis')
      .transition()
      .call(makeYAxis);

    // Update axis labels
    d3.select('#xLabel')
      .text(descriptions[xAxis]);

        d3.select('#yLabel')
      .text(descriptions[yAxis]);


    // Update correlation
    var xArray = _.map(data, function(d) {return d[xAxis];});
    var yArray = _.map(data, function(d) {return d[yAxis];});
    var c = getCorrelation(xArray, yArray);
    var x1 = xScale.domain()[0], y1 = c.m * x1 + c.b;
    var x2 = xScale.domain()[1], y2 = c.m * x2 + c.b;




    // Fade in
    d3.select('#bestfit')
      .style('opacity', 0)
         .attr({'x1': xScale(x1), 'y1': yScale(y1), 'x2': xScale(x2), 'y2': yScale(y2)})
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .style('opacity', 1);


         d3.select('#line')
      .style('opacity', 0)
         .attr({'x1': 0, 'y1': 100, 'x2': 100, 'y2':160})
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .style('opacity', 1);





  }


  //





  function updateScales() {
    xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([bounds[xAxis].min, bounds[xAxis].max])
                    .range([-10, 780]);

    yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([bounds[yAxis].min, bounds[yAxis].max])
                    .range([630, 100]);    
  }

  function makeXAxis(s) {
    s.call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom"));
  }

  function makeYAxis(s) {
    s.call(d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left"));
  }

  function updateMenus() {
    d3.select('#x-axis-menu')
      .selectAll('li')
      .classed('selected', function(d) {
        return d === xAxis;
      });
    d3.select('#y-axis-menu')
      .selectAll('li')
      .classed('selected', function(d) {
        return d === yAxis;
    });



  }

})
```

Main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Plotter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/svg.css">
     <style>
        #ymenu
        {
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
        line {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
     </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="chart">

            </div>



            <div id="ymenu">
            <h1>X axis</h1>
<!--                <h2>&uarr; Y axis</h2>
                <ul id="y-axis-menu"></ul>
                <h2>&rarr; X axis</h2>
 -->                <ul id="x-axis-menu"></ul>

            </div>

                <div id="menu">
                <h1>Y axis</h1>
                <ul id="y-axis-menu"></ul>
            </div>




        </div>


        <script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

      <!-- Twitter -->
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Data

```
[{"Patient_id":"22","Bp_Systolic":"130","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"80","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"174.633063","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"69.99986","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"25.109628","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"5.9","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"241","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"27","Bp_Systolic":"108","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"80","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"33","Bp_Systolic":"0","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"0","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"48","Bp_Systolic":"132","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"80","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"50","Bp_Systolic":"160","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"74","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"51","Bp_Systolic":"118","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"76","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"7.3","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"214","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"70","Bp_Systolic":"137","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"72","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"100","Bp_Systolic":"100","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"60","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"103","Bp_Systolic":"130","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"60","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"124","Bp_Systolic":"115","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"70","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"295.3793502","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"68.999862","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"43.71111","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"},
{"Patient_id":"126","Bp_Systolic":"120","Unit_systolic":"mm Hg","Bp_Diastolic":"70","Unit_diastolic":"mm Hg","Weight":"0","Unit_weight":"lbs","Height":"0","Unit_height":"inches","Bmi":"0","Unit_Bmi":"kg/m2","A1C":"0","Unit_A1C":"%","Cholestrol":"0","Unit_Cholestrol":"mg/dl"}]
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there, most of it probably unrelated to the specific feature you are trying to add. Any way you can reduce it to a minimal, self contained set of code+html+data to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mikehadlow/93b471e569e31af07cd3)?

Comment: Was having no idea where to put it. That's why posted all the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a line connecting circles upon mouse hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598332/create-a-line-connecting-circles-upon-mouse-hover)